# I wanna keep index in "pd.Series(a,index=).unique" code

Tags: arrays, pandas, indexing, unique, series

I have a problem with `pd.Series(a).unique()`

I made a `Series`, and I used `.unique()`.

However, this deletes the `pd.Series` index.

How can I made unique Array with original index?

Comment: Use `.drop_duplicates`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.unique()` you can use `.drop_duplicates()`:

```
x = pd.Series([1,2,3,1,1,2,4,5,6], index=list("abcdefghi"))

print(x)
a    1
b    2
c    3
d    1
e    1
f    2
g    4
h    5
i    6
dtype: int64
```

`.drop_duplicates()` will remove all duplicates from the Series while maintaining reference to the index. You can choose whether you want to keep the index location of the "first" or the "last" duplicated item via the `keep` argument:

```
# Keep the first entry of each duplicated value
x.drop_duplicates(keep="first")

a    1
b    2
c    3
g    4
h    5
i    6
dtype: int64
```

```
# Keep the last entry of each duplicated item
x.drop_duplicates(keep="last")

c    3
e    1
f    2
g    4
h    5
i    6
dtype: int64
```